# Trying to sort a linked list using a merge function?

Tags: c++, linked-list, mergesort

I have written a function to merge two singly linked lists. For example, if `A = 1 2 3` and `B = 3 4 5` and I merge them both, I get `A = 1 2 3 3 4 5` and `B = NULL`. What I want to do now is to write a function which sorts a singly linked list using the mergesort algorithm (somehow using my merge function). For mergesort, if I'm not wrong, I would have to break the linked list in half in some way and then do the rest of the work. I have a small outline written down on how I want to do it. I'm not sure how I would go about doing the splitting at the moment. Any help is appreciated!

```
          List mergeSort(List L) {
           if(|L| > 1) {
              split L into L1 and L2;
              L1 = mergeSort(L1);
              L2 = mergeSort(L1);
              return(merge(L1,L2));
           }
          }
```

My merge function below:

```
void mylist::merge(mylist& b)
{
    if (!this->isSorted() || !b.isSorted())
        cout << "error" << endl;
    Node* ptr1 = b.head;
    Node* prev_a = NULL;
    Node* curr_a = head;
    Node* curr_b = ptr1;
    while (curr_b) {
        if (curr_a && head->key < ptr1->key) {
            prev_a=curr_a;
            curr_a = curr_a->next;
        }
        else {
            Node* b_next = curr_b->next;
            curr_b->next = curr_a;
            if (prev_a) prev_a->next = curr_b;
            else head = curr_b; // curr_b is first element in 'a'
                prev_a = curr_b;
            curr_b = b_next; 
        }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Realize that the problem is trivial if both lists have a length of 1.

Comment: Heard of bottom-up mergesort? Works very well with linked lists

Comment: @Smac89 Not really, how would I implement that?

Comment: @sparta93 Here is a [link](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/22mergesort/) with the [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOUe8Q9jQow), and [another](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation) and [finally](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/171/Syllabus/7-Sort/merge-sort5.html). Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

To divide the list into two halves, two pointers can be used.

Both pointers start at the head of the list. One pointer move every two steps, while the other
move one step each time. 
When the fast pointer reach null, the slower pointer will points to the middle of the list.

`ListNode *fast(head->next), *slow(head);
        while(fast && fast->next) {
            fast = fast->next->next;
            slow = slow->next;
        }`